# How to create hyperlink using GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We are working on migrating multiple on-premises SQl Server Databases into RDS MySQL (AWS) 5.7 and we got a procedure which is using Stuff for XML function in SQL SERVER.

Got to know that GROUP_CONCAT can help to d the analytical part of it but is there any way to create the hyperlink as well in RDS MySQL?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable !

Comment: MySQL always returns the result as plain text. Only client interpretation may consider returned text as a hyperlink.